# Problems with trying to embed 2010 Excel Chart into 2010 PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I've had quite a frustrating afternoon trying to embed charts from an Excel spreadsheet into a PowerPoint presentation.

The charts in Excel are driven by a validated list (drop-down list) where the data will change when a new name is selected in Excel. My PowerPoint presentation contains about 40 slides with each individual slide allocated to a unique person who appears in my Excel drop-down list.

Here is the problem; I am able to copy from Excel the chart I want and paste-special into PowerPoint(using the paste special Microsoft Office Graphic Object option). When I insert the next slide into the PowerPoint, return to my Excel file and select the next name from the drop-down list to generate a new chart, copy and paste special Microsoft Office Graphic Object option into PowerPoint, the new chart (with the new person) comes up fine but the first slide with the first person now changes to the 2nd person I just selected.

How can I continue to use the drop down option to select new individuals and generate new charts without changing everybody else? Do I need to generate 40 worksheets within my file for each individual person? (not really wanting to do this but if it's the only option, then I'll have to do it).

Somebody out there must know a better way.

Comment: I don't suppose you could share the excel file and the powerpoint file? It would be easier (for me at least) to see the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately these files are confidential as they contain Doctor / Patient information and are protected under HIPPA rules

Answer (score 1):

If it is not necessary for the chart to change automatically when the data for each person does, you can paste the chart as a picture or static chart:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/copy-excel-data-or-charts-to-powerpoint-HA010204555.aspx
(See: Step 5 under "Paste a chart[...]", **Paste as picture**)

Comment: I need to update the information on a monthly basis which is why the connection between the Excel & PowerPoint files must be maintained. Otherwise, I have to re-invent the file each month which is something I'd rather not do.

Comment: Eurgh. I suspect you've outgrown the functionality of Excel in this instance then. I can only suggest that, in place of the dynamic worksheet that you have, you create 40 different worksheets with a different person on each one. That's not a 'solution' though.

Answer (score 1):

> > Do I need to generate 40 worksheets within my file for each individual person?

Basically, yes. The connection  between the Excel file and the PowerPoint file is one to one. The chart may be embedded into several slides. But as soon as one slide sends the parameters to the Excel file,  the Excel chart changes. These changes are reflected on all slides where the chart is embedded.

You need to understand that there is only one instance of the Excel chart, regardless of how many PowerPoint slides you have with an embedded Excel chart.

So, in order to have 40 different dynamic charts displaying on your PPT, you will need to create 40 different dynamic charts somewhere and load these into your presentation.